# \input files with graphics in directories

Tags: graphics, input, directory

I have a directory structure consisting of a a *Main* folder in which there are subfolders *Chapter1*, *Chapter2*, ...

Each of these subfolders contains a tex file and a number of image files that are to be used in that particular chapter only.

The chapter files are included in a `main.tex` which resides in the main folder and consists basically of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \input{Chapter1/chapter1.tex}
    \input{Chapter2/chapter2.tex}
\end{document}
```

I am aware that I can include image files in a chapter.tex by specifying the path relative to the Main folder, e.g. in `chapter1.tex` I could write:

```
\includesvg{Chapter1/img}
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying the folder (or to specify it only once)? I'd rather write:

```
\includesvg{img}
```

Comment: In the [svg package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg) is described a \svgpath command.

Comment: @vipa True, I can add the location of image directories in main.tex using \svgpath{} and it works. My only issue is that I can't use the same image file name in two different chapters. Is it possible to specify the svgpath specifically for the inputted files only or only alltogether for main.tex?

Comment: I think that is not a good practice having files with the same names. You can create a folder only for the images of your document.